# Dynamic xib layout for iPhone and iPad

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad, xib

I have an xib file that you can see in the image below.

[image]

I would like to know how I can make it so that it lays itself out correctly when being used in either iPhone or iPad devices.

Please note that the text in the labels is just used as a placeholder.

So far, I can adjust the width of

- **1997 to 1998** label
- **SalesDescription** label

and the positioning of the images without any trouble, the issue I am having happens when I try to layout the bottom line of UILables. It gets completely messed up

This is what I am trying to achieve

- **Card** should stay in the same position and not change width
- **023** should also stay in the same position and not change width
- **Num** should change its position horizontally depending on the device type but maintain its width
- **8** should change its position relative to **Num** however its width should change independently
- **Uni** and **0052** should behave like **Num** and **8**

With that in mind, is this possible? If it is, then I was hoping maybe someone can give me some pointers or a tutorial they think could help. I have looked at a few tutorials, however the relative positioning is what is throwing me off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The things you are trying to do are all fairly easy to solve with Autolayout constraints.

There is a bit of a learning curve, but it will be well worth the effort. Pretty much everything you wish to do can be done with no code to maintain.

Here is a good primer on Autolayout:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/64392/video-tutorial-beginning-auto-layout

Comment: okay so I almost have it I think.. The only change I need to make is making **8** lables width dynamic depending on the amount of text.. I did not see a way to do that in the video tutorial... do you know how?

Comment: Remove any width constraints on those items you wish to grow with more text, or make any width constraints "greater than or equal to" and set a min value. In Interface builder, be sure that "Intrinsic Size" is set to "Default(system defined)". Also, make sure that for "Num:", "Uni:" etc, that the x position constraint is set relative to the preceding view, so everything moves right as the amount of text grows.